# Wordpress: How Many WordPress Plugins Should I Install on my Site?

Tags: wordpress

Currently I have installed 6 plugins in my wordpress site. The performance of wordpress site is slow down because of it. Please let me know How Many maximum WordPress Plugins Should I Install on wordpress Site?

Comment: I think this question is **primarily opinion-based** Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Kishor, the problem is not the number of plugins. In some cases a single plugin causes more performance drop than others. Instead, you need to identify what the problems are.

Comment: Thank you @LajosArpad!!!

Comment: You are welcome, I am happy my answer helped you.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: you need to use the plugins you need to use. Regardless of their number. There are no two identical plugins, so the exact performance drop is affected by the things the plugins you are using are doing.

Since your problem is performance, you need to identify which plugins are making your site slow. This is the thing I would do if I were you:

- identify the plugins which are making the site slow
- identify the cause why the plugins are making the site slow
- fix the problem if possible, use another plugin if there is a better alternative or write the plugin yourself

How to identify the set of plugins causing performance drop:

- disable all plugins
- enable the plugins again one-by-one, testing performance after enabling each plugin. When a plugin turns out to be dropping performance, disable it to be able to find out which other plugins are dropping further the performancce

How to identify the cause of which a plugin drops the performance of the site:

- check plugin settings
- benchmark the plugin, see which functions/features are slowing your site

**So, it is not about the number of plugins, but it is about what the plugins are actually doing. If you have a large database, then you might want to use a caching system or write your own.**

Answer (score 0):

**Not only plugin slow down your web site. it depends on many things. For improve speed of your site try below things.**

```
 1. Minify your css
 2. Minify your js
 3. Minify your html
 4. Compressing Images
 5. Avoid bad request
 6. Optimize the order of styles and scripts
 7. Defer parsing of JavaScript
 8. Specify image dimensions
 9. Serve scaled images
 10. Specify a cache validator
 11. Leverage browser caching
 12. Remove query strings from static resources
 13. Specify a Vary: Accept-Encoding header
 14. Specify a character set early
 15. Avoid CSS @import
 16. Make fewer HTTP requests
 17. Add Expires headers
 18. Avoid HTTP 404 (Not Found) error
 19. Put CSS at the top
 20. Remove duplicate JavaScript and CSS
 21. Put JavaScript at bottom
 22. Make favicon small and cacheable
 23. Configure entity tags (ETags)
```